# windows azure mongodb tutorial not working

Tags: windows, node.js, azure, azure-storage

i followed the following tutorial:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/website-with-mongodb-(mac)/

and executed app.js just as the tutorial said but i got:

No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

I was wondering what does the tutorial mean by:

You must replace the connection string above with the connection string for the MongoDB server you created earlier. For example, mongodb://mymongodb.cloudapp.net/tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you received means "there is no connectivity between your node.js application and MongoDB server". This [tutorial](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/website-with-mongodb-%28mac%29/) has a very important step to install MongoDB as below:

**Create a virtual machine and install MongoDB**

- This tutorial assumes you have created a virtual machine in Windows Azure. After creating the virtual machine you need to install MongoDB on the virtual machine:
- To create a Linux virtual machine and install MongoDB, see [Installing MongoDB on a Linux Virtual machine.](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/mongodb-on-a-linux-vm/)

So if you have completed above steps you must have created your MongoDB installed Virtual Machine DNS name as "Your_MongoDB_VM_name.cloudapp.net", if not please finish this step.

So if you have installed MongoDB on Linux Virtual Machine and if your DNS name is "Your_MongoDB_VM_name.cloudapp.net then in App.js you will change the following line as beow:

```
var taskList = new TaskList('mongodb://Your_MongoDB_VM_name.cloudapp.net/tasks');
```

The above change will let your Node.js application to connect with MongoDB server running on Linux machine and this change must needed in your node.js application to work.